# INVALID_RESOURCE_ID when Authorization.Capture is called on an authorized payment using sandbox account

Tags: paypal, capture

I am using `PayPal.1.6.0\lib\net45\PayPal.dll`

I created a payment with `authorize` intent and have the successfully authorized `authID` (`Payment.Cart`) and the `PayPal.APi.Payment.id`.

When I try to call the `Authorization.Capture(apiContext, Capture)` with the `authID`, I get

```
{   
  "name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",  
  "message":"The requested resource ID was not found",  
  "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",  
  "debug_id":"d73f6a0c1b8bc"
}
```

I tested this using my sandbox account.

Trying the link gets me a 'page not found error'. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that i was looking at the wrong 'authorization code'. It is not the ((Payment)executedPayment).cart as posted in my original question but ((Payment)executedPayment).transactions.FirstOrDefault().authorization.id

I was able to use the correct authCode and am able to capture my authorization. executedPayment is the return value from Payment.Execute method.